# Slide transition with vue isn't working properly

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

I've built a navigation that has a hamburger slide menu. The menu works fine, except for the slide css transition I am trying to use. Basically, my code ignores the "sliding effect" of the transition all together. [An example of the transistion I am trying to achieve from the W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav)

*note:* I am using tailwind css framework to set the width of slide menu instead of setting the width in `.sidenav`: `<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav bg-black w-2/3 sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3">`

```js
Vue.component('navigation',{
    template: '#navigation',
    methods: {
      openSlideMenu(){
        this.$emit('open-slide');
      }
    },
});

Vue.component('slide-menu',{
    template: '#slide-menu',
    methods: {
      close(){
        this.$emit('close-slide');
      }
    },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showSlideMenu: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openSlideMenu(){
      this.showSlideMenu = true;
    },
    closeSlideMenu(){
      this.showSlideMenu = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to /* .slide-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="x/template" id="navigation">
  <div>
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between bg-red-light h-12 ">
      <div v-on:click="openSlideMenu()" class="cursor-pointer p-8">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="x/template" id="slide-menu">
  <div>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav bg-black w-2/3 sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3">
      <i @click="close()" class="closebtn cursor-pointer" >&times;</i>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <transition name="slide">
    <slide-menu v-show="showSlideMenu" v-on:close-slide="closeSlideMenu()"></slide-menu>
  </transition>
  <navigation v-on:open-slide="openSlideMenu()"></navigation>

<main>
  <h1>Some Content</h1>
</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.slide-enter-active {
  animation: menu-slide .5s;
}
.slide-leave-active {
  animation: menu-slide .5s reverse;
}
@keyframes menu-slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

... is about all you need. And `height: 100vh;` on the menu, of course:

```js
Vue.component('navigation',{
    template: '#navigation',
    methods: {
      openSlideMenu(){
        this.$emit('open-slide');
      }
    },
});

Vue.component('slide-menu',{
    template: '#slide-menu',
    methods: {
      close(){
        this.$emit('close-slide');
      }
    },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showSlideMenu: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openSlideMenu(){
      this.showSlideMenu = true;
    },
    closeSlideMenu(){
      this.showSlideMenu = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.slide-enter-active {
  animation: menu-slide .5s;
}
.slide-leave-active {
  animation: menu-slide .5s reverse;
}
@keyframes menu-slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="x/template" id="navigation">
  <div>
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between bg-red-light h-12 ">
      <div v-on:click="openSlideMenu()" class="cursor-pointer p-8">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="x/template" id="slide-menu">
  <div>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav bg-black w-2/3 sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3">
      <i @click="close()" class="closebtn cursor-pointer" >&times;</i>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <transition name="slide">
    <slide-menu v-show="showSlideMenu" v-on:close-slide="closeSlideMenu()"></slide-menu>
  </transition>
  <navigation v-on:open-slide="openSlideMenu()"></navigation>

<main>
  <h1>Some Content</h1>
</main>
</div>
```

---

By the way, [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) is not w3schools. w3schools are a tick trying to monetize displaying ads to people who are searching for the official documentation.

If you're confused, always search for MDN.

Why? Because MDN is not maintained by Mozilla alone. It's a joined effort of Mozilla, Google, Microsoft, Samsung and thousands of individual developers. Including W3C [read the article](https://www.w3.org/blog/2017/10/w3c-to-work-with-mdn-on-web-platform-documentation/).

The connection between MDN content and W3C content is now automated. While w3schools need to pay their employees to keep their content up to date, MDN gets the updates automatically, from the people setting the standards. And you'll always find the link to the Official Recommendation on the MDN page for a particular property, method or element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, my mistake on the W3C. 

My only question is why does it work with `height: 100vh;` and not 100%?

Comment: Answer is in the [official spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property): *"If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'"*. You'd need `height: 100%` on both `body` and `html` for `height:100%` to work on a `position:fixed` element. I find `height: 100vh` much more reliable (and shorter!) :).

Comment: Well, to be exact, you need to pass `height:100%` down on all parents from `<html>` to your `position:fixed` element so that `height:100%` works on your fixed elem. In your case, it would mean: `body, html, #app, #app > * { height: 100%; }`